# VestaCp удаление мусора после выполнения Cron

Tags: php, cron, vesta

есть крон который **срабатывает каждую минуту**, сайт на php кроны реализованы в виде модуля в котором есть контроллер который определяет екшены самих кронов и роутинг который определяет **url** того или иного крона.

Когда добавленный крон по url в панели vestaCp срабатывает, по адресу **/home/admin** появляются файлы следующего типа (пример, название файла соответствует названию крона): **notice.1 notice.2** ..... и так каждое выполнение, **в день каталог засоряется на 1440 не ненужных файлов.** 
Возможно кто то знает, как можно либо отключить запись выполнения крона в vestaCp, либо же подскажет как лучше реализовать автоматическую очистку этих файлов.
Спасибо.

**Скрин примера создаваемых файлов.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это обычные уведомления от cron, отчеты о выполнении, могут содержать ошибку, если выполнение задания не удалось.

Чтобы отключить эти уведомления, нужно в конец команды cron добавить следующий код (через пробел):

```
>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Этот код значит, что уведомления будут отправляться в `/dev/null`, т.е. в пустоту.

Подробнее: https://habr.com/ru/post/138591/

Команда удаления этих файлов, запускайте по крону:

```
find /home/admin -maxdepth 1 -name 'update_*' -delete
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, я использовал схожую команду да бы не получать уведомление о выполненной работе крона на почту "> /dev/null &2>&1", заменив на вашу, результата по файлам не было, они все так же продолжили добавляться в каталог один за другим по мере выполнения крона.

Comment: Покажите команду

Comment: wget https://my_site.com/cron/update_data >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: А что в файлах? Может там сообщение о проблеме, которую нужно исправить?

Comment: Нет, Файлы пусты если крон не выполнился по определённому условию, а если выполнился то в файлах соответствующая информация которая прописана у крона на выходе, когда шли уведомления на почту, никаких ошибок указано не было, все было со статусом 200.

Comment: Похоже проблема не с cron. Попробуйте добавить параметр `-q` для `wget`. Это отключит его сообщения.

Comment: добавил, но результата ноль, файлы так и создаются

Comment: Добавил скрин с примерами файлов, все они пустые, в них записываются данные с крона если есть, если например в конце крона в exit добавить ('end'), то в файле  запишется слово end.

Comment: В общем, сложно сказать почему эти файлы образуются, у меня идей больше нет, это нетипичная проблема для Vesta. В вопросе вы пишите, что вас устроит вариант чистки этих файлов. Добавил команду в решение.